# Apache server gets unreachable on a sudden

Tags: apache, debian, downtime

I'm not sure on which kind of community to post this question, but as i thought it could be a bug, i'll take a chance. 
Let me start with my situation. I've got a webserver (apache) running at home for over the last 3-4 years. First started off with Mandriva Spring 2011 release as OS, and as of this year moved over to Debian. 
When running Mandriva the only situation when my server was unreachable was when i had it shut down manually. Since a few weeks i noticed that occasionally the server gets unreachable, while the pc which serves as server is still running.

When i reboot the pc, everything is back to normal and my website reachable.

I'm unsure whether it's true, but it seems to be that the server gets unreachable after an (uncertain to me) amount of time.

I am running Debian with Apache 2 and PHP5.

Could this be a known bug, ready to be squished?

[EDIT:]
Forgot to add the url to my website, here it is:
http://nannies.no-ip.org/~leden

Comment: What's the error you get? Did you try a telnet on port 80 (presumably)?

Comment: On trying to visit my website i'm getting the 504 Gateway Timeout error. I'm not quite familiar with telnet, except from the e-mail function i once used a few years ago, can you explain what you mean? 

Besides, i forgot to add the url to my website, here it is:
http://nannies.no-ip.org/~leden